# How to split a C implementation file into several files with single header file

Tags: c++, c, g++

I have a C/C++ application, with a header file / implementation file pair.

Before:

---

```
// ===================================================
// Filename:         "bitwise.cpp"
// ===================================================
// --> "C" specific headers:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ===================================================
// --> same header:
#include "bitwise.hpp"
// ===================================================

uint8_t byte_and
  (uint8_t A, uint8_t B)
{
  return (A & B);
} 

uint16_t word_and
  (uint16_t A, uint16_t B)
{
  return (A & B);
} 

uint32_t dword_and
  (uint32_t A, uint32_t B)
{
  return (A & B);
} 

// other function's implementations

// ===================================================
```

---

```
// ===================================================
// Filename:         "bitwise.hpp"
// ===================================================
#ifndef BITWISE__HPP
#define BITWISE__HPP
// ===================================================
// --> "C" specific headers:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ===================================================
// --> same header:
// ???
// ===================================================

uint8_t byte_and
  (uint8_t A, uint8_t B);

uint16_t word_and
  (uint16_t A, uint16_t B);

uint32_t dword_and
  (uint32_t A, uint32_t B);

// other function's prototypes

// =================================================== 
#endif // BITWISE__HPP
// ===================================================
```

---

The main file is similar to this:

---

```
// ===================================================
// Filename:         "main.cpp"
// ===================================================
// --> "C" specific headers:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ===================================================
// --> myapp headers:
#include "bitwise.hpp"
// ===================================================

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int ErrorCode = 0;

    // ...

    uint8_t A = 7;
    uint8_t B = 5;
    uint8_t C = byte_and(A, B);

    // ...

    uint16_t A = 7;
    uint16_t B = 5;
    uint16_t C = word_and(A, B);

    // do something else

    // ...

    uint32_t A = 7;
    uint32_t B = 5;
    uint32_t C = dword_and(A, B);

    // do something else

    // ...

    return ErrorCode;
} // int main(...)

// ===================================================
```

---

Since the "bitwise.cpp" has become too large, I want to split it into several "*.cpp" files.

And, keeping a single "bitwise.hpp" file,
and also want the main file, not having to include each specific implementation "*.cpp" file.

After (Looking to achieve something similar to this):

---

```
// ===================================================
// Filename:         "bitwise_byte.cpp"
// ===================================================
// --> "C" specific headers:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ===================================================
// --> same header:
#include "bitwise_byte.hpp"
// ===================================================

uint8_t byte_and
  (uint8_t A, uint8_t B)
{
  return (A & B);
} 

// other function's implementations

// ===================================================
```

---

```
// ===================================================
// Filename:         "bitwise_word.cpp"
// ===================================================
// --> "C" specific headers:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ===================================================
// --> same header:
#include "bitwise_word.hpp"
// ===================================================

uint16_t word_and
  (uint16_t A, uint16_t B)
{
  return (A & B);
} 

// other function's implementations

// ===================================================
```

---

```
// ===================================================
// Filename:         "bitwise_dword.cpp"
// ===================================================
// --> "C" specific headers:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ===================================================
// --> same header:
#include "bitwise_dword.hpp"
// ===================================================

uint32_t word_and
  (uint32_t A, uint32_t B)
{
  return (A & B);
} 

// other function's implementations

// ===================================================
```

---

```
// ===================================================
// Filename:         "bitwise.hpp"
// ===================================================
#ifndef BITWISE__HPP
#define BITWISE__HPP
// ===================================================
// --> "C" specific headers:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ===================================================
// --> same header:
// ???
// ===================================================

// include smaller implementation files here (maybe):

// include "bitwise_byte.cpp" or "bitwise_byte.hpp"
// include "bitwise_word.cpp" or "bitwise_word.hpp"
// include "bitwise_dword.cpp" or "bitwise_dword.hpp"

// =================================================== 
#endif // BITWISE__HPP
// ===================================================
```

---

I'm not using namespaces or external variables, or class declarations, only global functions. Each individual implementation "*.cpp" files,
is independent of the others.

I want the main file to keep unchanged, without having to modify the "include" in it. The individual "*.cpp" files can be changed, and the "*.hpp" also can be changed.

Can this be done ?
Because, `if (CanBeDone == TRUE)`, How can be done ?

I tried to look in previous posts, but, didn't find an answer.

[Note: I didn't finished the question, and I already have 3 down votes, without explanation, looks like trolling]

Comment: Hmmm... you have to compile both cpp files and then link them? Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: @Alexis The example wasn't finished when you replied.

Comment: For performance reasons, you should make a bunch of *header* files and use the `inline` keyword.  The original header file can include all the new ones, then the consumer files needn't change at all.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Right. I already consider the `inline` option, plus other performance tricks, but, I wanted to design the library's declarations first.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Right. Sorry, I forgot. Your acomment about "original header file" matches "Ari Malinen" answer. I didn't get it, the first time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add all of the function prototypes to `bitwise.hpp` and include it to all files that need any of the functions.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Note: I wanted to avoid to put the function prototypes, and use a `include` declaration instead, but, It seems, is not possible, and, your answer is the most close thing, to what I looking for. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works, using @Ari Malinen idea, in case someone may require it:

---

```
// ===================================================
// Filename:         "bitwise_byte.cpp"
// ===================================================
// --> "C" specific headers:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ===================================================
// --> same header:
#include "bitwise_byte.hpp"
// ===================================================

uint8_t byte_and
  (uint8_t A, uint8_t B)
{
  return (A & B);
} 

// other function's implementations

// ===================================================
```

---

```
// ===================================================
// Filename:         "bitwise.hpp"
// ===================================================
#ifndef BITWISE__HPP
#define BITWISE__HPP
// ===================================================
// --> "C" specific headers:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ===================================================
// --> same header:
// ???
// ===================================================

uint8_t byte_and
  (uint8_t A, uint8_t B);

uint16_t word_and
  (uint16_t A, uint16_t B);

uint32_t dword_and
  (uint32_t A, uint32_t B);

// other function's prototypes

// =================================================== 
#endif // BITWISE__HPP
// ===================================================
```

---

```
// ===================================================
// Filename:         "bitwise.cpp"
// ===================================================
// --> "C" specific headers:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// ===================================================
// --> same header:
#include "bitwise.hpp"
// ===================================================

// Implementation of functions removed.

// ===================================================
```

---

The "bitwise_*.cpp" files, like "bitwise_byte.cpp", where removed from the project. "mainfile.cpp" is kept unchanged.

Other files like "bitwise_word.cpp", are used, but, doesn't appear in the example, to avoid making the example difficult to read.

I wanted to avoid to put the function prototypes, and use a include declaration instead, but, It seems, is not possible.